# Jsonwebtoken - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'from')

Tags: vue.js, jwt, vuejs3

I getting below error in browser console when I add jsonwebtoken.

below is my code in .js file.

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';    
const decodedToken = jwt.decode(_token);
```

[image]

can post your suggestions and ansewrs, if anyone face similar issue in jsonwebtoken plugin.

Comment: Try a var name without a leading underscore. E.g. refactor `_token` to `token`. I had an issue where vue3 didnt like a leading underscore (in some places, not all). Worth a shot.

Comment: It's a commonjs library, whereas you need ESM support [not provided by jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/655).  In summary, you should use a different library.

Comment: I used different library, for now i see this is workaround for this issue.